# How to force loading of autoloaded class?

Tags: ruby

I've opened a class ([from the OmniAuth Identity library](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-identity/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/identity.rb#L13)) to alter the forms it produces. The library uses [autoload](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload), so in order for the patch to work I need to force the library to load, but what I've tried so far results in errors, this is my best guess so far:

```
OmniAuth::Strategies::Identity if autoload? OmniAuth::Strategies::Identity
```

> uninitialized constant OmniAuth::Strategies::Identity (NameError)

Would anyone be able to tell me how this can be done? Any help or insight will be much appreciated.

Ruby v1.9.x
OmniAuth Identity v1.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the autoload is just a magic way to reduce the number of `require` statements, you can use exactly that to enforce the loading of a certain file:

```
require 'omniauth/strategies/identity'
```

Comment: Ah! Ingenuity passes me by so easily :D Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you simply want it to be loaded, can you not just use the following as code to ensure that it is loaded?

`OmniAuth::Strategies::Identity`

Comment: Apparently not, and I don't know why.